# Error matching square bracket literal in string with JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having an issue with matching a square bracket in a string with a regular expression in Javascript. I have tested the regex below, and it works for me:

```
"step_users[0]​[step]​[name]​".match(/step_users\[\d*\]/)
```

This regex matches the substring "step_users[0]", but what I really need to match is the substring "step_users[0][step]". I tried modifying the regex as follows, but it fails for me.

```
/step_users\[\d*\]\[step\]/
```

In fact, if i even add on the second '[', it fails. So, this also fails:

```
"step_users[0]​[step]​[name]​".match(/step_users\[\d*\]\[/)
```

Why would it match '[' for the first square bracket, but fail on the second?

Comment: Try give us a **non-working** jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a zero-width character in there!

```
"[0]​[".length === 5
"[0]​[".charCodeAt(3) === 8203
```

[8203](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29#Spaces_in_Unicode) is the word boundary character, a zero-width-space character. In fact, you have it between every pair of braces!

Remove it manually or dynamically as you fetch the data.

How I found it was simple. Your regex should have worked. So, I looked where it stopped working. An easy trick to find these zero-width spaces is to Shift-Arrow along the string.

Edit: A second after submitting, I thought of an easy way to remove it:

```
var destroyZWS = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(8203), "g");
yourString.replace(destroyZWS, "");
```

This creates a regular expression, which globally searches for the specific ZWS character, and then replaces each occurrence with the empty string.

Comment: Well...there we go then. Thanks. I suppose that's because I copied it out of the html name attribute output in my web inspector console.

Comment: @slave2zeros Enjoy. I just edited in a simple way to remove that bugger.

Comment: Well, normally they'll be coming from the name attribute of an HTML element, not copied from Safari's web inspector. It just happened to be a problem while testing in the console.